# Check table data with Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

After filtering a list of movies, I am trying to write a cucumber step definition to check whether each column of that table contains the correct values. 
The step definition reads:

```
 When I check "ratings_PG"
 And I press "ratings_submit"
 Then the "ratings" field within "table#movies" should contain "PG"
```

The step handler I am using reads:

```
    Then /^the "([^]*) field(?: within (.*))? should contain "([^]*)$/
```

But I receiving this error message: "Ambiguous match of "the "ratings" field with "table#movies" should contain "PG"

I am unsure what the error is suggesting and similarly unclear on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is a step handler. Please show us your step definition itself, as in `.feature` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have got a complicated regular expression you are using here. I'd suggest something simpler that may not be as flexible, but makes it easier to see what's going on:

```
Then /^the "(.*?)" field within "(.*?)" should contain "(.*?)"$/
```

This will capture the three parameters you are trying to pass.

Answer (score 0):

The "Ambigous match" fires when cucumber is not able to match your step definitions. Either the regexp is confusing fields : the step match but fiedls are confusing : missing parameter for a datable for example. 
Or you have two step definition very similar and cucumber cannot determine which one to take.

Comment: So the problem appears to be that capybara cannot locate the "ratings" field within the movies table. Is there any documentation on using cucumber to search table data?